# how to append vlc in Explorer and netscape?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using the following code:

```
var vlcTag = "<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' width=100% height=" + div_size + "% autoplay='no' loop ='yes' id='vlc" + tagid + "'></embed>";
                document.getElementById(tagid).innerHTML = vlcTag;
                var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc" + tagid);
                var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=16:9");
                vlc.playlist.add(url, streamtype, options);
                vlc.playlist.play();
```

But when I run this code I found the error as:

```
unable to get property playlist of undefined or null reference.
```

Comment: when you get the element by ID, you're only getting the HTML element, not the javascript object associated with it, so it doesn't have a property `playlist`

Comment: DLeh, Please give me the proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the javascript object because you haven't added the tag to the DOM yet. Set the inner HTML of some page element to be the VLC tag, which will then actually load the VLC embed onto the page. Once it's actually loaded, then you can get the javascript object from it.

```
 var divToAddTo = document.getElementById("vlc" + tagid);
 divToAddTo.innerHtml = vlcTag;
 var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc" + tagid);
 //now you should actually have access to the vlc object.
```

Comment: Thanx Dleh for your suggestion.... it works but it doen't works in IE , do u have any solution of it?

Comment: sorry, i don't have any experience with vlc embeds. you'll have to provide more information about what's not working. try debugging through your code and looking at what values of `vlc` are available